# Why does Visual Studio fail to run after making any code changes without first Rebuilding?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using VS 2015
So I recently broke up a ASP.NET MVC website by separating some class files and putting them into a new empty project so that I could reference them in another website that shared the same database.

However, now when I run the new MVC website it seems that I must hit Rebuild after any .vb code changes I make. If I try to run the project without first Rebuilding, i get this error

How can I get it to run without needing to Rebuild after every minute code change?

Update -- I copied the classes from the secondary project into the main project, and then removed the reference to the secondary project and removed the project from the solutions window. I rebuilt once and now it works even after making code changes. So it is definitely something wrong with how I referenced the second project.

> The compiler failed with error code -532462766.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express>C:\WORKFOLDER\AutoBuySell\AutoBuySell\bin\roslyn\vbc.exe
>   /t:library /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\a1d8a5b8\69270ed1_d477d101\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\bf3ec3c8\85563ea7_d677d101\WebGrease.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\6c26b0d7\808a18d1_d477d101\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\c830bbc7\0766fca1_d378d101\AutoBuySell.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\9b5d34b0\907955d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\8a01191d\fc926cd1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\4b3c34cc\80e376d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\7cb65127\bd9b4ad1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\500f9172\df3016ce_d477d101\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\ce41882f\2f9f60d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\24d305d0\13550ed0_d477d101\EntityFramework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\478bd033\c71b40d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\b397b865\b5596fa6_d677d101\Antlr3.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\06316d92\6c5df4cd_d477d101\System.Web.Razor.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\e64f9481\315882d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\1121362c\fd8002d1_d477d101\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\f4cc84fc\1eb010ce_d477d101\System.Web.Helpers.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\1ff0f97c\bd9d94a6_d677d101\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\1565b35a\c3d047ce_d477d101\System.Web.Mvc.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\7eee271b\cf371dce_d477d101\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\1ad19649\493f03ce_d477d101\System.Web.Optimization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\279706a6\dcc212d0_d477d101\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\91a2e492\87d9f280_d378d101\AutomotiveClasses.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\eb3ddd67\568a5ba7_d677d101\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\1e137664\61c03bce_d477d101\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\1e4b9dcf\107b20d1_d477d101\Owin.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\618bccc6\a74335d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\a08bfcea\8e9e1ace_d477d101\System.Web.WebPages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\assembly\dl3\cbf4aa47\700929d1_d477d101\Microsoft.Owin.dll"
>   /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\App_global.asax.vbv6bflu.dll" /D:DEBUG=1
>   /debug+ /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\"
>   /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Collections.Specialized,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,System.Configuration,System.Linq,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.DynamicData,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls,System.Xml.Linq
>   /optionInfer+ /langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\"
>   /optionInfer+ 
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\App_global.asax.vbv6bflu.0.vb"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\46897f63\9b824d22\App_global.asax.vbv6bflu.1.vb"

Comment: Maybe you're having some trouble with the dependencies on your solution. Have you tried changing the build order?

Comment: From what I can tell, the build order is correct. In fact, it wont let me change anything. It has the classes project listed first, and the website listed second. And shows the website is dependent on the classes project.

Comment: You are asking why compiled code needs to recompile after making a code change?

Comment: No. Normally I can run the project, which Builds automatically, after making code changes. But now, after making code changes, I have to hit Rebuild manually first and then run the project.

Comment: Your throwing an unhandled exception that's why it's terminating.

Comment: Well, i've never seen that error page before. Normally it tells me the problem, the line number or something. This is not the typical stack. So I'm clueless on what the error is to begin with or why rebuilding before running fixes it.

Comment: Running the same issue, but on a WebApi project and it's totally random...